# Calling a variable from another script

Tags: php

im trying assign values to my variables in ascript by calling a function and variables from another script, but currently im getting errors saying

> Undefined property: stdClass::$Boys in
>
> Undefined property: stdClass::$Girls in

im calling a function in a script called report.php from my script

report.php

```
public function projectReport($ID){
    $get_con = $this->getConnection();
    $result = mysql_query($query, $get_con);
    $rep = new stdClass();
    if(false !== $result){
        $multis = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $count = new stdClass();
            $count->Boys = (int)$row['males'];
            $count->Girls = (int)$row['females'];
            $multis[] = $count;

        }
        $rep->multiples = $multis;

    }
return $rep;
    }
```

function body of my script

```
$report = new Report();
$log = $report->projectReport($ID);
if($log != false){
    $Boys = $log->Boys;
    $Girls = $log->Girls;
    print_r($Boys);
    print_r($Girls);
}

return $log;
```

Comment: what is $mat? is $multfs a misspelled version of $multis? what does your method return? you use $log as a stdClass object, but it might be an array or anything else depending on the result of your method. Please clarify.

Comment: sorry it was a mistake... edited the the code

Comment: `projectReport` does not *return* a value...

Comment: Still not clear what $rep is and if projectReport method is part of Report class (I assume it is). Also it does not return anything and you're trying to assign/use the result as a stdClass object.

Comment: $rep is a std class.. i added that to be clear

Comment: Now `projectReport` returns object which has property `multiples` of type `array`. It has no `Boys` or `Girls` property.

Comment: it does have inside the the $multis

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your $log can never be false so you don't need to check that. Alhtough multiples attribute might be missing.

Try this:

```
$report = new Report();
$log = $report->projectReport($ID);
if(property_exists($log, 'multiples')){  //check if multiples attribute exists
    foreach ($log->multiples as $m)      //walk through every multiples record
    {
        $Boys = $m->Boys;                //get Boys and Girls attributes values and print them
        $Girls = $m->Girls;
        print_r($Boys);
        print_r($Girls);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that's not what you wanna achieve, but that how it should work based on what you've got so far.